# How to Remove Single Blank Line Using Notepad++ Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove just the last line in a file if it's a line containing nothing. I am using Notepad++.

## Details

Say I have a text file open in Notepad++. If the last line of a file is the empty string, I want to remove it. I want to do this using Notepad++'s native find/replace functionality, with regexes.

## Use Case

I often encounter this case after I copy a file from Visual Studio to Notepad++. The reason for searching how to do it with a regex is: when recording a macro in Notepad++ it's more stable to use a regex find/replace than just manually deleting a character. The manual delete might be sensitive to file length.

Comment: Find `\R\z`, Replace: `EMPTY`

Comment: OK excellent. It's not for my sake so don't worry. Just for others who might want to check this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R\z`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R       # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
\z       # end of file
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to search for this regex: `\r\n$(?!\r\n)` and replace it with nothing (the empty string).